# HTML Img tag and srcset attribute

Tags: html, css

I am a bit confused about the use of `srcset` attribute in the HTML `img` tag. I read several tutorials on the Web but I think stuff doesn't work as these tutorial report. First of all, let's start with an easy example:

```
<img src="assets/img/software-developer.jpeg" alt="Some Stuff" srcset="assets/img/software-developer-300.jpeg 300w, assets/img/software-developer.jpeg 450w">
```

I have two images:

- `assets/img/software-developer.jpeg` 450x450 pixels
- `assets/img/software-developer-300.jpeg` 300x300 pixels

Now I use Chrome Developer Tools for tests, but whatever screen size I select I always see that `assets/img/software-developer.jpeg` is downloaded. I can see it in the Developer Tools Properties tab looking at the property `currentSrc`.

**Can anyone help me to understand why?** I want that:

- for screen with size >= 450px then `assets/img/software-developer.jpeg` is downloaded
- for screen with size < 450px then `assets/img/software-developer-300.jpeg` is downloaded

Another thing that it's not clear to me is: **what happens with screen size < 300px?**

If the image with lowest width is `assets/img/software-developer-300.jpeg` that is 300x300 pixels, how I can modify the code to let it resize (become smaller in this case) to fit the viewport?

For example, Developer Tools by defaul has Galaxy Fold device that has a width of 280 pixel. In this case, both the images don't fit the screen size: **how I can define my srcset to let it resize in this situation?**

Web is full of information about this stuff, at a first read things are a bit confusing so I decided to start with small tests. The first tests I decided to work on is with `srcset` and check if the image downloaded is the one expected. It seems the tag doesn't work as expected. I know that I am missing something, hoping someone here can help to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `sizes` tag in there.

> `sizes` defines a set of media conditions (e.g. screen widths) and indicates what image size would be best to choose, when certain media conditions are true.

The correct way to write the code to achieve would be

```
<img src="assets/img/software-developer.jpeg" alt="Some Stuff" sizes="(max-width: 449px) 300px, 450px" srcset="assets/img/software-developer-300.jpeg 300w, assets/img/software-developer.jpeg 450w">
```

You can read more about it here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#how_do_you_create_responsive_images

Comment: No it doesn't work. I included your code but currentSrc is always ```assets/img/software-developer.jpeg```. To avoid cache issues I also used Incognito Window or Right-click on Reload -> Empty cache and hard reload. Just FYI I also tried with sizes in my tests but no luck. Moreover on Galaxy Fold 280px width the image is even cropped.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the answer by myself. First of all, the `srcset` tag alone doesn't make too much sense, it must be always used in conjuction with `sizes`.

The `srcset` tells the browser which imahes are available, for example:

```
srcset="assets/img/software-developer-300.jpeg 300w, assets/img/software-developer.jpeg 450w"
```

Basically this attributes tells to the browser:

Hey there are two images you can use:

- assets/img/software-developer-300.jpeg 300 pixel wide
- assets/img/software-developer.jpeg 450 pixel wide

Now you have to tell the browser to use the former for screen < 450 px and the latter for screen >= 450. You can do this with the attribute `sizes`:

```
srcset="assets/img/software-developer-300.jpeg 300w, assets/img/software-developer.jpeg 450w" sizes="(max-width: 449px) 300px,  (min-width: 450px) 450px"
```

Basically, for screen up to 449px you can use the 300px image version, for screen starting from 450px you caan use the 450px version. The problem is that there are phone with screen size less than 300px (i.e. Gaalaxy Fold is 280px wide). On these screen the image is cropped and to avoid this you must tell the browser that if the screen size is less than 299px the image must be resized to 100vw. Now in my case, 100vw doesn't work properly so I just reduced it to 75vw.